# Neo4j doesn't start on debian

Tags: neo4j, debian

I use  neo4j-community-2.0.1-unix.tar.gz:

I delete old data in the database:
t@konrad:~/neo4j$ rm -rf ./data/

I start the application:
t@konrad:~/neo4j$ ./bin/neo4j console

> : Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the
>   Neo4j manual. Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
>   /home/triptop/neo4j/data/log was missing, recreating... Using
>   additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
>   -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -Dlog4j.configuration=file:conf/log4j.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled 2014-04-02 10:10:01.149+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms
>   based on -1 2014-04-02 10:12:29.005+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Exception
>   when stopping
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@4ec143d8
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>   java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:73)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:448)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:523)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:185)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:523)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:123)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:307)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
>           at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.createDb(CommunityDatabase.java:62)
>           at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:120)
>           at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:158)
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>           at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:743)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:723)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.writeOut(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:164)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.force(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:178)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.releaseCurrentLogFile(XaLogicalLog.java:700)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.close(XaLogicalLog.java:725)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:69)
>           ... 16 more 2014-04-02 10:12:29.037+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Exception when stopping
>   org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@2bf11e9f
>   Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@4ec143d8' failed
>   to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@4ec143d8' failed
>   to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:528)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:185)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:523)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:123)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:307)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
>           at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.createDb(CommunityDatabase.java:62)
>           at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:120)
>           at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:158)
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:73)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:448)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:523)
>           ... 14 more Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>           at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:743)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:723)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.writeOut(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:164)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.force(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:178)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.releaseCurrentLogFile(XaLogicalLog.java:700)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.close(XaLogicalLog.java:725)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:69)
>           ... 16 more 2014-04-02 10:12:29.057+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Lifecycle exception Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@2bf11e9f'
>   failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>   org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@2bf11e9f'
>   failed to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:528)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:123)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:307)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
>           at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.createDb(CommunityDatabase.java:62)
>           at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:120)
>           at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:158)
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@4ec143d8' failed
>   to stop. Please see attached cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:528)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.stop(LifeSupport.java:155)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.stop(XaDataSourceManager.java:185)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:523)
>           ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:73)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.stop(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:448)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:523)
>           ... 14 more Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>           at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.writeInternal(FileChannelImpl.java:743)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:723)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.writeOut(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:164)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.DirectMappedLogBuffer.force(DirectMappedLogBuffer.java:178)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.releaseCurrentLogFile(XaLogicalLog.java:700)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaLogicalLog.close(XaLogicalLog.java:725)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.LogBackedXaDataSource.stop(LogBackedXaDataSource.java:69)
>           ... 16 more 2014-04-02 10:12:29.080+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: Chained lifecycle exception Component
>   'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@55aa75c1' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception. org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException:
>   Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions@55aa75c1' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:509)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.run(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:307)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase.(EmbeddedGraphDatabase.java:63)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory$1.newDatabase(GraphDatabaseFactory.java:92)
>           at org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder.newGraphDatabase(GraphDatabaseBuilder.java:198)
>           at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.createDb(CommunityDatabase.java:62)
>           at org.neo4j.server.database.CommunityDatabase.start(CommunityDatabase.java:120)
>           at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:158)
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87)
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension@287c20ab' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:509)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:115)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.extension.KernelExtensions.start(KernelExtensions.java:118)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503)
>           ... 10 more Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component
>   'org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource@2f4c076f' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:509)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.bringToState(LifeSupport.java:411)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.add(LifeSupport.java:324)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager.registerDataSource(XaDataSourceManager.java:236)
>           at org.neo4j.index.lucene.LuceneKernelExtension.start(LuceneKernelExtension.java:79)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503)
>           ... 13 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.(IndexProviderStore.java:85)
>           at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.newIndexStore(LuceneDataSource.java:302)
>           at org.neo4j.index.impl.lucene.LuceneDataSource.start(LuceneDataSource.java:225)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503)
>           ... 18 more Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
>           at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
>           at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.position(FileChannelImpl.java:290)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.write(IndexProviderStore.java:169)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.create(IndexProviderStore.java:153)
>           at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.index.IndexProviderStore.(IndexProviderStore.java:61)
>           ... 21 more 2014-04-02 10:12:29.141+0000 DEBUG [API] Failed to start database. 2014-04-02 10:12:29.144+0000 DEBUG [API]
>   org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Startup took longer than
>   120000ms, and was stopped. You can disable this behavior by setting
>   'org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout' to 0. Error code: 1
>           at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:211)
>   ~[neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.start(Bootstrapper.java:87) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1]
>           at org.neo4j.server.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:50) [neo4j-server-2.0.1.jar:2.0.1] 2014-04-02 10:12:29.180+0000 DEBUG
>   [API] Failed to start Neo Server on port [7478]

Any ideas why this may happen?

My java is:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Comment: Could you check the messages.log file in the data/graph.db directory for errors? It could also just be that startup takes longer than 2 min, you can set a longer timeout by specifying the "org.neo4j.server.startup_timeout" setting in neo4j-server.properties. Setting it to 0 means it never times out the startup.

Answer (score 1):

Your system only allow 1024 open files. Read the first line of your startup message:

```
Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual
```

see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/linux-performance-guide.html#_setting_the_number_of_open_files for details.